# Setting parameters to simulink's multiply block

Tags: matlab, simulink

I'm working on a simulink model found on the internet and all multiply blocks are fed with the following thing instead of a constant block:
[image]

My question is how to edit this "a" value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That must be a source created using "Signal and Scope Manager". You can right click on that and choose "Generator parameters" to open the dialog for that source. If it is a source create with Constant block it will open the Constant block dialog, where you can change constant value. The displayed "a" is probably the name of the source. You can see doc for this at

http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/signal-and-scope-manager.html